# Run python script in loop and print output to file

Tags: python

I have the following python script:

```
import something
response = requests.get('https://example.com/folder/1')
data = stuff_here
print(data)
```

I would like to run this script for URL values 1 to 100 and save the output to *1.txt, 2.txt ... 100.txt*.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: For loop and write to file: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
# Firstly you import what you need to import
import something

# For-loop which runs from values 1 to 101 (101 is non-inclusive)
# with each value being stored in to 'i'
for i in range(1, 101):
    # Runs requests.get() method on the URL
    # URL is made by f-formatting a string ('{i}' will get replaced with the value of 'i')
    response = requests.get(f'https://example.com/folder/{i}')

    # Does 'stuff_here' and stores it in 'data'
    data = stuff_here

    # Prints out data
    print(data)

    # with keyword opens the file f'{i}.txt' in "w" mode,
    #  and stores is in to the 'file' variable.
    # f'{i}.txt' is, again, an f-formatted string which replaces '{i}' with the value of i
    # "w" mode is writing mode, you can write to a file while using it
    with open(f"{i}.txt", "w") as file:
        # Writes the contents of 'data' to the file 'file'
        file.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import requests


input_list = []

for i in range(1, 101):
    input_list.append(('https://example.com/folder/{}'.format(i), "{}.txt".format(i)))


for input_ in input_list:
    req = requests.get(input_[0])
    if (req.status_code == 200):
        result = req.text
    else:
        result = "Failed Request {}".format(req.status_code)
    with open(input_[1], "w") as f:
        f.write(result)
```

Comment: You can use for loop to make urls and files.Now you have to write 100 urls and files.

Comment: for 100 urls and text file, the code is not optimal

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Still not optimal, there is no reason to store 100 URLs in a list.